# How do you assign custom template for Posts page (under Front page displays setting)

Tags: pages, templates, page-template

How do you assign custom template for Posts page (under Front page displays setting)?

`Settings > Reading` in backend.
I notice once I set Posts page to specific page, the Template dropdown on edit page disappears. Also tried `page-blog.php` but did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend bookmarking this Image from Wordpres Codex [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)

As you can see on it Blogs page uses `home.php`  as template while front page is using `front-page.php`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and recommendation. Yes, I really need that page bookmarked ;)